# Choosing the correct metabolic rate

Tags: weightlifting, calories, crossfit, daily-caloric-intake

I'm trying to determine my metabolic rate for the TDEE calculator but I'm a little confused on how to choose the correct one. A little context about myself: I'm a 23 year old, male, Software Engineer, and work out every day for an hour at a crossfit gym.

Other than the 1 hour I get at crossfit, most of my day is sitting at a desk and/or walking to meetings.

How would I classify myself in terms of my metabolic rate? I feel like all the information I got online is too vague

Answer (score 1):

All the information you get online IS vague. Everything you find online are ways to simply estimate an average of what you can expect based on factors like your age, sex, height, etc. If you really want to figure out your metabolic rate as accurately as possible, get it tested. You can find places that will put you through breath by breath resting metabolic rate tests to accurately find out how much you burn at rest. [Body Comp](https://www.body-comp.com/testing/metabolic-testing/) is in example of one, specifically the one I did, to find out my own body composition and resting metabolic rate.

As far as 'how to classify yourself,' if you're looking at [BodyBuilding's](https://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/calculate-your-total-daily-energy-expenditure-tdee.html) TDEE calculator, you would fall under the `moderately active` category.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this [TDEE Tracker](https://www.reddit.com/r/nSuns/comments/6lv33j/faq_about_tdee_30/) made by a friendly reddit user.

I believe that it is better than any TDEE calculator because of two reasons.

1. Activity levels are not rigidly defined
2. You may not be tracking your calories accurately

With this spreadsheet, as long as you track calories (doesn't have to be accurate, just consistent), it'll find your TDEE based on how YOU track your calories (maybe you over or undershoot)